# Can't retrieve the data from API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I'm trying to retrieve the price data from the following API but I keep getting this error message when I execute the code.

```
def upbitask_xrp_krw_get():
    result = requests.get("https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP&count=1").json()
    return result["highPrice"]
```

And the error message I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 194, in <module>
main()
  File "test.py", line 130, in main
upbitask_xrp_krw = Decimal(upbitask_xrp_krw_get())
  File "test.py", line 10, in upbitask_xrp_krw_get
"https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP&count=1").json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 793, in json
return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I've successfully accessed the data from other API which only has {} brackets whereas this one has [] brackets which I assume is the problem here?

Comment: What is the value of `requests.get("https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP&count=1").` and its type. Check whether the json function exists for that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the `requests` module you need to import it in your script first. this is true for any Python module you wish to use.

It seems the object returned by the API endpoint is a list of JSON and not simply a JSON object. Try this:

```
import requests

def upbitask_xrp_krw_get():
    result = requests.get("https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP&count=1").json()
    return result[0]["highPrice"]
```

The `[0]` indicates to return the first item of the list.

Here is the result:

[image]

**Update**

It seems there is a rate limite that prevents to query the API to often. When you reach the limit you get a 403 response code. Here is an example how you could manage it:

```
import requests

def upbitask_xrp_krw_get():
  result = requests.get("https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP&count=1")
  if result.status_code == 200:  # Http code 200 means success
    json = result.json()
    high_price = json[0]["highPrice"]
  else:
    high_price = None

return high_price
```

Comment: The error is occurring when the request is made, not when accessing items in the JSON object

Comment: I was able to run the script I pasted above and it worked... I have tried a second time and got a permission error (403). I have updated my answer with the result.

Comment: @Han In order to use the `requests` module you need to import it in your script first. this is true for any Python module you wish to use.

Comment: thanks @Alexis.Rolland, so the code you gave me works but likewise, I'm getting mixed results of error&data. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Han yes, as mentioned by GracefulRestart below, there might be a rate limit which prevents you to query the endpoint to often. I faced a 403 error as well when querying it several time. Let me update my script above to work around this.

Comment: @Han I've updated the answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland getting the error message "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: I think this is because I define the data later as decimal as follow "upbitask_xrp_krw = Decimal(upbitask_xrp_krw_get())"

Comment: @Han there was a typo in there I have corrected it as `high_price = json[0]["highPrice"]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you're getting that error, but you can bypass it by just calling `json.loads()` on the text of the request:

```
result = requests.get("https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP&count=1")
result_text = result.text
json_data = json.loads(result_text)
return json_data[0]["highPrice"]
```

You'll need to `import json` however. Also, you'll need to get the dictionary out of the list (hence the `[0]`).

---

EDIT: This is actually really bizarre: sometimes it's printing out a result and other times it's raising an error. It could have to do with the request being different over a very short period of time.

Comment: Once you've converted the string to json data, I find it can be helpful to pprint.pprint(json_data) to see the structure of the data.

Comment: json_data is an array. So the return line needs to -
return json_data[0]["highPrice"]

Comment: it is raising an error sometimes because the api is returning HTTP 403.

Comment: @TerryA is there any reason you aren't just using `result.json()`?

Comment: thanks @TerryA so how would I go about mitigating this error?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I couldn't reproduce the error when doing `json.loads()`

Comment: @TerryA I'm not sure what you mean by that. Instead of saving `result.text` to a variable named `result_text` and then passing it into `json.loads(result_text)`, you can jump straight to JSON by using `result.json()` (It's the [6th line run in the first example box of the `requests` docs.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)). That way you don't have to `import json` and it simplifies your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may work better:

```
def upbitask_xrp_krw_get():
    result = requests.get("https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP&count=1").json()
    return result[0]["highPrice"]
```

Your result is a list of json data.  Just need to select the index you want in the return value.

EDIT:  oh neat, there are different results after subsequent requests.  There must be some kind of rate limiting, the first time I hit the API I get the list, the next time i hit it I just get a 403 response

Comment: Agreed with the 403, I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I m just a beginner in python i did some research and this worked for me

```
import json
    import requests
    url ='https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/1?code=CRIX.UPBIT.KRW-XRP&count=1'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    print(data[0]['code'])
```

This worked for me

[image]

Thanks,